# CRC16 table Vs polynomial

Tags: crc16

I've got 2 crc calculators that I think should produce the same checksum. The lookup calculator

```
table=[0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50A5, 0x60C6, 0x70E7, 0x8108, 0x9129, 0xA14A, 0xB16B, 0xC18C, 0xD1AD, 0xE1CE, 0xF1EF,
       0x1231, 0x0210, 0x3273, 0x2252, 0x52B5, 0x4294, 0x72F7, 0x62D6, 0x9339, 0x8318, 0xB37B, 0xA35A, 0xD3BD, 0xC39C, 0xF3FF, 0xE3DE,
       0x2462, 0x3443, 0x0420, 0x1401, 0x64E6, 0x74C7, 0x44A4, 0x5485, 0xA56A, 0xB54B, 0x8528, 0x9509, 0xE5EE, 0xF5CF, 0xC5AC, 0xD58D,
       0x3653, 0x2672, 0x1611, 0x0630, 0x76D7, 0x66F6, 0x5695, 0x46B4, 0xB75B, 0xA77A, 0x9719, 0x8738, 0xF7DF, 0xE7FE, 0xD79D, 0xC7BC,
       0x48C4, 0x58E5, 0x6886, 0x78A7, 0x0840, 0x1861, 0x2802, 0x3823, 0xC9CC, 0xD9ED, 0xE98E, 0xF9AF, 0x8948, 0x9969, 0xA90A, 0xB92B,
       0x5AF5, 0x4AD4, 0x7AB7, 0x6A96, 0x1A71, 0x0A50, 0x3A33, 0x2A12, 0xDBFD, 0xCBDC, 0xFBBF, 0xEB9E, 0x9B79, 0x8B58, 0xBB3B, 0xAB1A,
       0x6CA6, 0x7C87, 0x4CE4, 0x5CC5, 0x2C22, 0x3C03, 0x0C60, 0x1C41, 0xEDAE, 0xFD8F, 0xCDEC, 0xDDCD, 0xAD2A, 0xBD0B, 0x8D68, 0x9D49,
       0x7E97, 0x6EB6, 0x5ED5, 0x4EF4, 0x3E13, 0x2E32, 0x1E51, 0x0E70, 0xFF9F, 0xEFBE, 0xDFDD, 0xCFFC, 0xBF1B, 0xAF3A, 0x9F59, 0x8F78,
       0x9188, 0x81A9, 0xB1CA, 0xA1EB, 0xD10C, 0xC12D, 0xF14E, 0xE16F, 0x1080, 0x00A1, 0x30C2, 0x20E3, 0x5004, 0x4025, 0x7046, 0x6067,
       0x83B9, 0x9398, 0xA3FB, 0xB3DA, 0xC33D, 0xD31C, 0xE37F, 0xF35E, 0x02B1, 0x1290, 0x22F3, 0x32D2, 0x4235, 0x5214, 0x6277, 0x7256,
       0xB5EA, 0xA5CB, 0x95A8, 0x8589, 0xF56E, 0xE54F, 0xD52C, 0xC50D, 0x34E2, 0x24C3, 0x14A0, 0x0481, 0x7466, 0x6447, 0x5424, 0x4405,
       0xA7DB, 0xB7FA, 0x8799, 0x97B8, 0xE75F, 0xF77E, 0xC71D, 0xD73C, 0x26D3, 0x36F2, 0x0691, 0x16B0, 0x6657, 0x7676, 0x4615, 0x5634,
       0xD94C, 0xC96D, 0xF90E, 0xE92F, 0x99C8, 0x89E9, 0xB98A, 0xA9AB, 0x5844, 0x4865, 0x7806, 0x6827, 0x18C0, 0x08E1, 0x3882, 0x28A3,
       0xCB7D, 0xDB5C, 0xEB3F, 0xFB1E, 0x8BF9, 0x9BD8, 0xABBB, 0xBB9A, 0x4A75, 0x5A54, 0x6A37, 0x7A16, 0x0AF1, 0x1AD0, 0x2AB3, 0x3A92,
       0xFD2E, 0xED0F, 0xDD6C, 0xCD4D, 0xBDAA, 0xAD8B, 0x9DE8, 0x8DC9, 0x7C26, 0x6C07, 0x5C64, 0x4C45, 0x3CA2, 0x2C83, 0x1CE0, 0x0CC1,
       0xEF1F, 0xFF3E, 0xCF5D, 0xDF7C, 0xAF9B, 0xBFBA, 0x8FD9, 0x9FF8, 0x6E17, 0x7E36, 0x4E55, 0x5E74, 0x2E93, 0x3EB2, 0x0ED1, 0x1EF0]
crc=0xFFFF
for byte in b'123456789': crc=(crc<<8)^table[(crc>>8)^byte]; crc &= 0xFFFF
print('%.04X'%crc)
```

prints 29B1 whereas the poly calculator

```
PRESET = 0xffff; POLYNOMIAL = 0x8408 # bit reverse of 0x1021
crc = PRESET
for c in b'123456789':
  crc = crc ^ c
  for j in range(8):
    if crc & 0x01: crc = (crc >> 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL
    else: crc = crc >> 1
print('%.04X'%crc)
```

prints 6F91. I don't understand why they are different?

Comment: One is shifting up, and the other is shifting down. The first is a forward CRC processing the most significant bit of each byte first, whereas the second one is a reflected CRC, processing the least significant bit of each byte first. Which one do you need?

Comment: I'd like the second one (or something like it) to produce the same result as the first one.

Comment: motto's answer has exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional non-table driven computation of this CRC species (CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE) is along the lines of:

```py
PRESET = 0xFFFF; POLYNOMIAL = 0x1021 
crc = PRESET
for c in b'123456789':
  crc = crc ^ (c << 8)
  for j in range(8):
    if crc & 0x8000: crc = (crc << 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL
    else: crc = crc << 1
crc = crc & 0xFFFF
print('%.04X'%crc)  # outputs 0x29B1 as expected
```

So, it xors each byte with the upper byte of the crc and processes the bits high end to low end (well, middle end).

Your method, on the other hand, xors each byte with the lower byte of the crc and processes the bits low end to middle end. That isn't equivalent – but, interestingly, if you feed it the input with each byte bit-reversed, then the resulting CRC will be bit-reversed. Kind of a mirror-image CRC, we could call it ... um, "CRC" I guess:

```py
mirror_input = bytes([(int(bin(ord(b))[2:].zfill(8)[::-1], 2)) for b in "123456789"])
# b'\x8cL\xcc,\xacl\xec\x1c\x9c'

mirror_crc = kris_mclean_crc(mirror_input)
# 0x8D94 == 0b1000110110010100
# 0x29B1 == 0b0010100110110001
```

So, no slightly neater implementation today I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't know why we need CRCs for 2 devices chatting at 9600 over 5cm of pcb track but tnx muchly for setting me straight.

Comment: Well it's just 2 devices at 9600 over 5cm today, but WHO KNOWS what tomorrow might bring? 6cm? ...7?